# Lubuntu 15.04 - Broadcom wi-fi wont work at all

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, 15.04, broadcom

Just installed Lubuntu 15.04 on an Acer Aspire 5100, the broadcom router is the BCM4311 model. I have tried a few different fixes but none of them seem to work. I have a few other Acer laptops that I will be installing Lubuntu 15.04 on as well (Aspire & Travel Mate) so I am hoping to find the right fix for the broadcom problem. Thanks :)

ETA: Terminal results of this command lspci -knn | grep 'Eth|Net' -EA2

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)     
  Subsystem: AMBIT Microsystem Corp. Device [1468:0422]     
  Kernel driver in use: wl    
06:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
  Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:009f]
  Kernel driver in use: 8139too
```

ETA: got the wireless to work finally but when I reboot it will try to connect to the ethernet 1st (I then have to right click on the network connection icon to tell it to connect to the wireless) any way to force it to try the wireless 1st? I have already removed the ethernet connection from the list of connections. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: I already tried the fixes in that question, none worked :(

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep 'Eth|Net' -EA2` terminal command.

Comment: If you have another question regarding why Ethernet connection is started, please, ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is
>   another process using it?

This usually means that another process, typically Update Manager, Software Center or Synaptic is open and has a hold on /var/log/dpkg. Please close whichever it is. Then in a terminal and with a temporary working internet connection, do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If it is not removed because it isn't installed, that's fine, just continue:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot and your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Well. OP does not have ANY network connection. b43 will not install. Do you know ho to install it offline?

Comment: The b43 driver is present by default, but it needs proprietary firmware.  The /pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_019-2_amd64.deb package on the live media is to pull the firmware out of a proprietary driver (Windows...etc.).  Easier to use an ethernet connection to install the nonfree firmware package.

Comment: If there is no internet access, follow the procedure at post #7 here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2098717

Comment: I do have internet access through the Ethernet cable